# trying to make navigation bar responsive after many attempts

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and new to CSS and html and I've been trying to make it so that my navigation bar would scale with the screen. I've tried watching tutorials and i just don't seem to be able to get it to work.
heres the code,

```
enter code here
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tello00/qaxwvk3f/1/

Comment: Your code appears to be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you have 5 items in your nav bar, you could just style them with width 20% each. Does this edit to your css work for you?

```
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;

}
#title-navigation {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    float : left;
    width : 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in css file

```
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;

}

li {
  display: inline;
}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){
  #title-navigation ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%; 
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #f00;
  }
}
```

in HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Swift Cusine | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="header-title">
      <h1>Swift Cusine</h1>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="title-navigation">
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Order</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Login</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Sign up</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="section-image">
      <h1>Swift Cusine</h1>
      <h3>Food delivered like a cheeta.</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="swift-cusine-info">
      <h1>Info</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sapiente, corrupti. Excepturi, omnis, consequuntur dolorum voluptates qui quia corrupti magni nostrum suscipit at labore modi similique neque, doloribus ullam ex. Autem.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
      <h1>Contact</h1>
      <p>need any help? have any questions? here are ways you can contact us!</p>
    </div>
  </main>
  <div id="footer-disclaimer">
    <footer>
      <p>Disclaimer: this is not a real website and no food will be orderd</p>
      &copy;
      <p>swift food</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this link into your 'head' tag in the main index page

```
    //Link

    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Copy these scripts at the end of 'body' tag

```
    //scripts

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And finally use this tempalate in your code and adjust the texts and links according to you..!!

```
    //template

    <div class="fixed-top">
      <div class="collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
        <div class="bg-dark p-4">
          <h5 class="text-white h4">Collapsed content</h5>
          <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </nav>
    </div>
```